# UICollectionView and Scrolling Program Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView inside of a normal UIViewController.

Inside the collectionview I have designed the reusable UI for the collectionviewcells in storyboard.

Inside of the collectionviewcell there is a label that displays the cells indexpath.row and 5 UIButtons which if selected, change color and stay selected.

I have set up the collectionview so that if more that 30 cells are requested the collectionview will page horizontally, the collectionview layout is also horizontal.

The application runs nicely, scrolls properly and lays out cells correctly.

**The problem** I am having is when you select for example **button A in cell 1** in the collectionviewcell (which is suppose to layout 100 cells) and page over two pages (60+ Cells) to **page 3, button A in cell number 75 is selected**. And further more if you scroll to the end (100 cells) and **scroll back to page 3**, button A in cell number 75 is on longer selected, but **button A in cell number 64 is selected**.

Here is some snippets of code:
cell.m - controls the action from the user.

```
- (IBAction)bubbleButtons:(id)sender {
    for(UIButton *bubbleCell in self.bubbleButtons) {
            if (bubbleCell.touchInside && !bubbleCell.selected) {
                bubbleCell.selected = YES;
            } else if (bubbleCell.touchInside && bubbleCell.selected) {
                bubbleCell.selected = NO;
            }
      }

 }
```

MainViewContoller.m - sets up cell from UICollectionViewCell made in storyboard

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        Cell *cell1;
        cell1 =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:zCellID
                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell1.numMainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d |",indexPath.row+1];
        return cell1;
```

I do not really understand what is wrong or what is causing this bug, I am assuming it has todo with the view being reloaded when a new part of the view becomes visible but that is just a guess. Help would be greatly appreciated.

- Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the reusable view is reused.

The proper way to do this is to create custom reusable view subclass.
And save the selection of those 5 button.

```
        cell1 =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:zCellID
```

This line here might or might not give you a new cell, it might give you a cell that is used before. So, you need to update the selection in there. Or it stay the same as the cell it's reusing.

Comment: So should I create a custom reusable view within the resablecell? Ultimately I need to be able to save the selected button and know which button the user selected in the OutletConnection of UIButtons bubbleButtons.

Comment: By reusable view, I meant the reusable cell. You need to save the selection or else it's not promised to be there. You can save the selection in the reusable ell subclass or better even save it in a modal else where. Remember that view is never used for store information.

Comment: But how would you detect which button from the outletconnection was selected and then save that selection for the specific cell and store the selection in, maybe, a dictionary? Because the cell index path comes from the MainViewController how would the cell subclass know which cell the button was selected in?

Answer (score 0):

The Uicollection only generate the cells that are been displayed at that moment, so when a cell disapier from the visible view, its been replace with the new one.

So when you seleted the cell 75 and you scroll down, until the cell 75 is no visible, and then you scroll back to cell 75, you are generating a new cell, with a new button that is not seleted because is new.

So what yo could do, is save which buttons had been selet, and in

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

ask if the button thats is been displayed at that moment need to be selected..

Hope its helps